# Ansible:- loop_var not working, value undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am trying to access the variable using loop, but it's not working for me.

playbook

```
---
- name: test looping
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    repos:
      - name: repo1
        os_list:
          - centos
          - rhel
        major_distribution_list:
          - 6
          - 7
          - 8
        archs:
          - noarch
          - x86_64
  tasks:

    - include_tasks: repo-paths.yml
      with_items: "{{ repos }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: repo

    - debug: msg="./{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}/{{ item.2 }}/{{ item.3 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ repo.os_list }}"
        - "{{ repo.major_distribution_list }}"
        - "{{ repo.name }}"
        - "{{ repo.archs }}"
```

But i am getting error repo variable is undefined.
Original Ouput:-

```
PLAY [test looping] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'repo' is undefined"}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Expected output:-

```
"msg": "./centos/6/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./centos/6/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./centos/7/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./centos/7/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./centos/8/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./centos/8/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./rhel/6/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./rhel/6/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./rhel/7/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./rhel/7/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./rhel/8/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./rhel/8/repo1/x86_64"
```

Please help me and please also tell if there is some alternative to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loop_control` statement is defined for the first task and relates only to it. It's not kept thru the rest of the playbook. If you want to use it in the `with_nested` task, it needs to be stated again.

The second problem you have is `with_nested`. Your `repos` variable is a list containing one element. To support iterating over the list, you should define your `debug` tasks in it's own file, and use `include_tasks` with `loop` over the list. Something like this

```
---
- name: test looping
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    repos:
      - name: repo1
        os_list:
          - centos
          - rhel
        major_distribution_list:
          - 6
          - 7
          - 8
        archs:
          - noarch
          - x86_64
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: my_tasks.yml
    loop: "{{ repos }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: repo

--- my_tasks.yml

- debug: msg="./{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}/{{ item.2 }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ repo.os_list }}"
    - "{{ repo.major_distribution_list }}"
    - "{{ repo.archs }}"

--- output 

ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'centos', 6, u'noarch']) => {
    "msg": "./centos/6/noarch"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'centos', 6, u'x86_64']) => {
    "msg": "./centos/6/x86_64"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'centos', 7, u'noarch']) => {
    "msg": "./centos/7/noarch"
}
..
..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this:

```yaml
    - debug: msg="./{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}/{{ item.2 }}/{{ item.3 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ repo.os_list }}"
        - "{{ repo.major_distribution_list }}"
        - "{{ repo.name }}"
        - "{{ repo.archs }}"
```

into a file named `repo-paths.yml`. This is because `with_items: "{{ repos }}"` runs loop over single task `include_tasks: repo-paths.yml` and passes the `repo` variable to tasks inside the imported file. The loop does not affect consequent tasks in the same file.